# R Suicide : Fatal error: unable to initialize the JIT

Tags: r

I have installed R on my windows server 2019 and installed Rcpp package, then compressed its installation to a zip file (R-4.0.2.zip).
In a C++ application on another machine, I decompress this R-4.0.2.zip, set R_HOME and PATH to point to the extracted directory and /bin/x64, respectively. I then load R.dll to run a simple R script.

I have run this application on my machine using the extracted R-4.0.2.zip and also another machine with no pre-installation of R where I have access to its graphical user interface. However, when I run it on another machine (server), which I don't have access to its graphical interface, the R suicides itself with a message in a messagebox (that I can only see with a windows debugger from its dump).

`Fatal error: unable to initialize the JIT`

```
user32!SoftModalMessageBox+0x228b [d:\xx\windows\core\ntuser\client\msgbox.c @ 1235] 
user32!MessageBoxWorker+0x2ec [d:\xx\windows\core\ntuser\client\msgbox.c @ 782] 
user32!MessageBoxTimeoutW+0xd5 [d:\xx\windows\core\ntuser\client\msgbox.c @ 439] 
user32!MessageBoxTimeoutA+0x102 [d:\xx\windows\core\ntuser\client\msgbox.c @ 483] 
user32!MessageBoxExA+0x10 [d:\xx\windows\core\ntuser\client\msgbox.c @ 369] 
user32!MessageBoxA+0x4e [d:\xx\windows\core\ntuser\client\msgbox.c @ 342] 
R!R_Suicide+0x39
R!setup_Rmainloop+0x954
```

Any idea what could be the potential problem for this? do I need to install a specific package such as `Rserve`, any specific firewall rule? [the CPP application and R script run on the same machine though]